# GitHub Push Alert

Tags: git, github, version-control, token

hello I'm newbie on GitHub, so I tried to push somebody's code on my repository which I have cloned, when I try push It asks  User name & Password, then it shows password Authorization removed, and shows me the username of the code Owner
github.com/somebody's user name/repository Name, why did this happened..? why did it hold the username of the owner,,, is it trying to get access from the owner, its already public Repo. :/

tried to push it via token, expecting to sync with my remote repo

Comment: I don't think you can do it without access to that repo by the owner. Instead try forking the repo, pushing the changes into the fork and then submitting a pull request to the original repo.

Answer (score 0):

To push the changes to your own repository, you need to create a fork of the original repository, make changes to the forked repository, and then push the changes to your own repository. You can authenticate yourself using a personal access token instead of your password. You can generate a personal access token by going to your GitHub settings and selecting "Developer settings" -> "Personal access tokens". Once you have generated a token, you can use it as your password when pushing changes to your repository.